# HowTo Web.config transformation in VS 2010 IIS Website without creating a Web Application Project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I would like to use web.config transformation but do not see the "Add Config Transforms" in the context menu when i right-click on my original web.config file.

I do not have a Web Application Project and cannot have one. My solution has a few projects for BLL, DAL etc, then i have a local IIS website for the main Website.

[image]

Under my local IIS website i have a web.config and have tried to add a web.Debug.config like such:
[image]

**How can i do web.config transformation using the localhost IIS website and not having to creating a Web Application Project?** **Is it even possible? Is creating a Web Application Project a requirement?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was recently reading up on this subject and to my knowledge you can not do web.config transformation in a Web Site project for one simple reason – Web Sites don’t have project files, which is where the msbuild configurations are stored. So if you need that functionality you will have to create a project file. But have a look at this blog which I think gives a better explanation for this.

http://andrewtwest.com/2010/02/25/using-web-config-transformations-in-web-site-projects/

Having said that if you do find out that im wrong, which i might be please keep me updated with what was your solution

Thanks